# Losing line breaks in string manipulation

Tags: bash

Howdie,

I have a bash script that installs phppgadmin and replaces the alias phppgadmin by !phppgadmin.

This is my script:

```
#installing phppgadmin and tell my Apache conf file to include it
apt-get install --force-yes phppgadmin && echo 'Include /etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf' >> /my/conf/apache2/apache2.conf

# the string manipulation
phppgadmin=`cat /etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf`
phppgadmin=${phppgadmin/Alias \/phppgadmin/Alias \/!phppgadmin}

#saving result
echo -e $phppgadmin > /etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf
```

This works well except line breaks get lost along the way, so of course Apache complains that file is not readable. I tried with cat -E, no success.

Any idea?

EDIT: Ok, it seems that i did not get what `cat -E` was doing. It actually substitutes line breaks by a dollar sign, so this is what I got now up and working:

```
phppgadmin=`cat -E /etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf`
phppgadmin=${phppgadmin/Alias \/phppgadmin/Alias \/!phppgadmin}
phppgadmin=${phppgadmin//$/'\n'}

echo -e $phppgadmin > /etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf
```

So, problem solved!

Comment: If you were able to solve your problem, please use the "Answer your question" button below and provide an answer for the community to see. You can accept this answer in two days, and you'll even get reputation for it if it is upvoted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify configuration files, **`sed`** is more reliable than bash:

```
sed -i 's|^Alias /phppgadmin|Alias /!phppgadmin|' /etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf
```

---

You are losing newlines because you passed `$phppgadmin` to `echo` unquoted, which means the shell splits the variable's contents at whitespace. Your original script would have worked if you used **`"$phppgadmin"`** instead.

Additionally:

1. Do not use `` `cat` ``, use `` `<file` `` or `$(<file)` instead.
2. `${phppgadmin//$/'\n'}` will destroy any *real* `$`'s the original configuration file might have had.

Rewritten script, *still* not as reliable as the `sed` command above:

```
conf=$(< /etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf)
conf=${conf/Alias \/phppgadmin/Alias \/!phppgadmin}
echo "$conf" > /etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf
```